# Node.JS bug trying to create a chat

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

I'm currently writing a chat application which will run on Heroku. I'm using Node.JS and Socket.IO for this task. It works perfectly when I run it locally but when I deploy it to heroku I get this error :

```
app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:724
app[web.1]:   rand.writeInt32BE(this.sequenceNumber, 11);
app[web.1]:        ^
app[web.1]: TypeError: Object
```

Here's the Socket.IO part of the code (the rest is just classic Express code) :

```
var socket = require('socket.io');
var io = socket.listen(app);

io.configure(function () { 
    io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]); 
    io.set("polling duration", 10); 
});

var usernames = {}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('adduser', function(username) {
      socket.username = username;
      usernames[username] = username;
      socket.join('room');
      socket.emit('action', username, 'connected');
      socket.broadcast.to('room').emit('action', username, 'connected');
    });
    socket.on('message', function(message) {
      socket.emit('message', socket.username, message);
      socket.broadcast.to('room').emit('message', socket.username, message);
    });
});
```

Has anyone got any idea on how to solve this bug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using right version of **node** and **npm** specified in **package.json**

```
"engines": {
    "node": "0.8.x"
    ,"npm": "1.1.x"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I didn't even know you could specify the version of node and npm to use...